# Como converter milisegundos em data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma conversão de milisegundos em data dentro de um campo em um json.

Por exemplo

```
$http.get("http://teste").success(function (dados) {

        ng.locations = $.map(dados, function(job) {

                return job.jobList;
        });
    });
},
```

exemplo do json

```
[

{
    "description":"Job de Teste",
    "jobList":[
        {
            "jobID":01,
            "jobState":"OK",
            "jobName":"TESTE",
            "jobCompleteTime":1407783800000 //tempo em milisec.
        }
    ]
}

]
```

Me retorna esse json, eu preciso converter um campo dentro do jobList antes do retorno. Como posso tratar especificamente apenas um campo antes do retorno?

Comment: Qual é o campo que tem a data? qual é a chave (key)? dá para colocar um excerto do JSON na pergunta?

Comment: OK. fiz a edição. o tempo em milisec está no comentário.

Comment: Otimo, já agora, só há um objeto por jobList, ou esse jobList é mesmo uma array com vários objetos?

Comment: é um array msm :) na implantação irá ter varios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro desse `.map()` têm de iterar todos os objetos da array e mudar/sobrescrever cada data.
Para percorrer os objetos pode usar um ciclo `for`. Depois têm de ir à propriedade correta e sobreescrevê-la

```
for(var i = 0; i < job.jobList.length; i++){
    var data = job.jobList[i].jobCompleteTime;
    job.jobList[i].jobCompleteTime = new Date(data).toString(); // fica "Mon Aug 11 2014 21:03:20 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)"
}
// aqui fazer o return job.jobList;
```

Se quiser formatar para outro formato, por exemplo: aaaa-mm-dd, pode fazer

```
for(var i = 0; i < job.jobList.length; i++){
    var data = job.jobList[i].jobCompleteTime;
    var d = new Date(data);
    job.jobList[i].jobCompleteTime = d.getFullYear()+ "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate();
}
// aqui fazer o return job.jobList;
```

Comment: Obrigado! Foi muito útil! :)

Answer (score 3):

É só passar o tempo em milisegundos para o construtor do tipo `Date()` :

```
tempo = //milisegundos
date = new Date(tempo);
alert(date.toString());
```

Comment: mas como faço para pegar o tempo da coluna exata do json? eu naoq uero converter o json inteiro. O json é imenso.

Comment: edite e coloque em sua questão uma instância do jobList

Comment: Ok fiz a edição. se puder me ajudar eu agradeço :)